# What is a good approach to reuse an Angular component that requires a different script in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I've started to learn angular recently and i have the follow situation:

I created a form component and i want to reuse it, changing things like title, fields,etc. This i can easy do with @Input(). My doubt is: for different forms, i have to execute different scripts ( in practice, different services ). For solve it, i did:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, NonNullableFormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { LeafletComponent } from 'src/app/map/leaflet/leaflet.component';
import { CreateService } from './services/create.service';
import { UpdateService } from './services/update.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-partner',
  templateUrl: './form-partner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-partner.component.scss']
})
export class FormPartnerComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild(LeafletComponent) leafletComponent!: LeafletComponent;
  @Input() title?: string;
  @Input() formType?: string; // create_form / update_form
  @Input() buttonTitle?: string;
  id?: string;
  formServiceMode: any;

  constructor(private formBuilder: NonNullableFormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute, private createService: CreateService,
     private updateService: UpdateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.formType === 'create_form') {
      this.formServiceMode = this.createService;
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        document: ['', [Validators.required]],
        ownerName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        tradingName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        address: [''],
        coverageArea: ['']
      });
    } else if (this.formType === 'update_form') {
      this.formServiceMode = this.updateService;
      this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') || '';
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        document: [this.id],
        ownerName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        tradingName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        address: [''],
        coverageArea: ['']
      });

    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
    this.formServiceMode.onSubmit(form, this.leafletComponent);
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.formServiceMode.onCancel();
  }

  formErrorMessage() {
    return 'Field required';
  }
}
```

As you can see, i insert a input "formType" that i can use in "ngOnInit()" to verify which service it corresponds. However, this way have, in my opinion,  two ( possibly more ) problems:

1 - Extense code with a large switch case deppending of number of form types.

2 - ( That one made me feel i was doing something wrong ) I need to have all functions declared directly in component. For example: If a 'update_form' requires a updateFunct() i will have to declare it here too. So, for a lot of different form types, i'll have a component with a lot of different functions ( and methods like updateFunct(), in really, will be used only for "update_form")

Sounds like a trivial question,i really feel it's not the best way to do. However,i've searched a lot but only found examples reusing components thinking on layout changes.

Trying to find a good way to reuse a same component but with different scripts in Angular.

Comment: I remember topic from Reddit, where more people preffered template driven instead of forms development. It confirms, what is better approach : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing forms is tricky, because of the problems you present. I think you are on the right track but I would suggest you de-couple the service from your form component and instead emit a submit event. Also you can simplify the code a bit:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-partner',
  templateUrl: './form-partner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-partner.component.scss']
})
export class FormPartnerComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild(LeafletComponent) leafletComponent!: LeafletComponent;
  @Input() title?: string;
  @Input() formType?: string; // create_form / update_form
  @Input() buttonTitle?: string;
  id?: string;

  @Output() submitted = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() canceled = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: NonNullableFormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') || ''
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        document: ['', this.formType === 'create_form' ? [Validators.required] : []],
        ownerName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        tradingName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        address: [''],
        coverageArea: ['']
      });
  }

  onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
    if (form.valid) {
      this.submitted.emit(form.value);
    } else {
      // handle validation here
    }
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.canceled.emit();
  }

  formErrorMessage() {
    return 'Field required';
  }
}
```

You will need to have separate instances of the form - one for handling updates, and one for creates.

update page:

```
<app-form-partner title="Update" formType="update_form" buttonTitle="Update" (submitted)="handleUpdate($event)" (canceled)="handleUpdateCancel()"></app-form-partner>
```

create page:

```
<app-form-partner title="New" formType="create_form" buttonTitle="Submit" (submitted)="handleCreate($event)" (canceled)="handleCreateCancel()"></app-form-partner>
```

The "handle" methods in turn call your services. Alternately you can inject your services with the `public` modifier and call them directly from your template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry to disturb but i'm still a bit confused... I'll need a service to treat this events, right? In this service, will i have the same problems? Moreover, you said reusing forms is tricky. In my project, i get into this problem so many times ( like in a table, too), what makes me think its a relatively common situation. What do you recommend in this case? Do separate components or try it this way? Ty again

Comment: I updated my answer, hope that helps